# Como treinar dois objetos com diferentes tamanhos para reconhecimento no OpenCv

Tags: android, c++, opencv

Olá, estou utilizando o OpenCv versão 2.4.11 para treinar o reconhecimento de placas de veículos para um software de estacionamento. O problema é quando treino para identificar a placa de carro, caminhonete, caminhão onde as placas utilizadas por eles são das mesmas dimensões o cascade fica 100%.

Quando eu treino para reconhecer as placas de moto junto com as placas de carro a resposta não é eficaz quando tento capturar as placas de moto, pois as dimensões são diferentes.

As placas de carros e caminhões etc. tem o formato de um retângulo já as motos é mais para um quadrado então se eu treinar os vetores de moto e demais veículos juntos, só vai funcionar o reconhecimento ou de um ou de outro.

Comment: Olá Fabrício. Qual é a proporção de exemplos de placas de motos para demais veículos? Você chegou a treinar dois classificadores separados (um para motos e outro para demais veículos)? Talvez assim seja mais fácil, devido a essas diferenças de dimensões que você menciona (aliás, outras diferenças que podem ser relevantes são o distanciamento entre os dígitos e a razão de aspecto deles).

Comment: P.S.: Apenas uma questão semântica: se você está usando Cascade, então não está "reconhecendo" as placas, mas sim localizando-as na imagem (isto é, encontrando uma região que se assemelha a uma placa veicular). Reconhecimento deve ser o próximo passo que você deseja fazer (em que a região de pixels vai ser literalmente "traduzida" em uma string do tipo "AAA 2222").

Comment: Sim eu cheguei a treinar os dois separados, e dá certo, mas ai levantaria outra questão: Como eu faria pra que meu software identificasse qual cascade usar, ou seja, carrego o cascade para identificar placas de motos mas o veículo analisado será um carro. Ta certo eu poderia especificar que é um carro que irei avaliar mas trata-se de uma entrada de estacionamento então tenho que fazer isso automático.

Comment: R: PS. Isso mesmo, estou usando o cascade para reconhecer o local da placa depois eu irei aplicar o OCR para o reconhecimento das letras.

Comment: Bom, em princípio se você fez usando as imagens de placas de moto como exemplos *negativos* para treinar o detector de placas de carros (e vice-versa), basta você aplicar os dois detectores. Apenas um deles vai te retornar um resultado. Assim, se você tiver um usuário humano você faz na maior parte das vezes de forma automática, e só pede auxílio ao humano (pra ele identificar se é carro ou moto) em caso de duplo-positivo (que idealmente, vai ocorrer bem pouco).

Comment: Esta pergunta está no momento com 3 votos para fechar, os 3 como "não é claro o que você está perguntando". Não sou entendendor da área de visão computacional, mas eu particularmente (acho) que entendi a pergunta. Alguma das pessoas que votou para fechar ou que irá votar para fechar, gostaria de dar maiores explicações sobre o possível fechamento?

Comment: Eu não acho que ficou obscuro o que eu perguntei, pelo contrário deixei a pergunta da forma mais clara possível. E a propósito fiz a mesma pergunta no site oficial do opencv.org e por se tratar de tamanhos diferentes deve ser feito treinos diferentes nesse caso.  http://answers.opencv.org/question/61317/how-to-train-two-objects-with-different-sizes-in-opencv/

Comment: Fabricio, eu não havia visto a sua última mensagem (sobre ter postado também no site oficial do OpenCV). Se você chegou a uma conclusão, por que não posta uma resposta nesta pergunta? Assim você também ajuda outras pessoas que no futuro possam ter a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Você tem razão...

Answer (score 3):

De todas as pesquisas que eu fiz a respeito desse assunto não foram satisfatórias, mas segundo respostas no site da Open CV chegamos a uma conclusão de que devemos treinar os dois tipos de placa separado, ou seja treinamos os vetores para busca de placa em um cascade para placas de veículos e outro cascade para busca de placas de notos.

Dentro do software é que devemos fazer a distinção, que em um momento antes da identificação o usuário informará se a placa é moto ou veículo (carro, caminhão, caminhonete).

Comment: Qualquer resposta que possa melhorar essa situação será bem vinda, com certeza.

Comment: Você chegou a discutir, ou testar, se o uso de imagens de um grupo como *exemplos negativos* do outro durante o treinamento melhora essa diferenciação durante o reconhecimento, conforme eu tinha sugerido? Talvez melhore muito os resultados, talvez não. Tudo depende do quão diferentes as features realmente são, mas a minha intuição diz que deve melhorar um bocado por causa das diferenças na distância entre os dígitos e na razão de aspecto das placas.

Comment: E, novamente, se os detectores ficarem suficientemente robustos, dá pra testar os dois na foto e escolher o objeto (carro ou moto) automaticamente. Somente se os dois derem positivo (dúvida) se perguntaria ao usuário. Ou, naturalmente, se o usuário desejar forçar uma resposta (essa opção sempre deve ser possível, pois garante que mesmo no caso de erros de detecção o usuário consiga escolher a opção correta).